# How to backup service based database in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project and i'm using a Service-based database(MyDatabase)
I added a button which create a backup file but it didn't work .
I removed try and catch and it gave me error on `ExecuteNonQuery` and it say's  Database 'MyDatabase' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
how can I backup a service-based database?
here is my code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string FileName = textBox1.Text + "\\my program" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() +
        "---" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString().Replace(':', '-');
        string qur = "Backup Database MyDatabase to Disk='" + FileName + ".bak'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qur, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Database backup created successfuly", "Buckup database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erorr", "Buckup database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a MySql DB Backup mechanism . Just for reference if it helps you . `string FileName = "db.sql";string constring = m_strMySQLConnectionString;string file = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Db\\"+FileName);using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()){using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
{cmd.Connection = conn;conn.Open();mb.ExportInfo.AddCreateDatabase = true;mb.ExportInfo.ExportTableStructure = true;
mb.ExportInfo.ExportRows = true;mb.ExportToFile(file);conn.Close();} } }`